# How to limit the number of requests being send by Axios?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

So basically I am using react js, redux, and axios in an app which uses axios to send requests. I have a particular redux action that is performed every time a button is clicked. The action sends an async axios request to a backend to run further logic. The problem here is that in production, nothing is stopping a user from spamming the button and possibly overloading the server. How could I limit the number of requests being sent? A reasonable amount in this case would probably be 1 request every 3-4 seconds. I've heard of an axios cancel token but I dont really understand it or how to use it. Thank you!